# Python Regex Sub - Use Match as Dict Key in Substitution

Tags: python, regex, perl, python-3.x

I'm translating a program from Perl to Python (3.3).  I'm fairly new with Python.  In Perl, I can do crafty regex substitutions, such as:

```
$string =~ s/<(\w+)>/$params->{$1}/g;
```

This will search through `$string`, and for each group of word characters enclosed in <>, a substitution from the `$params` hashref will occur, using the regex match as the hash key.

What is the best (Pythonic) way to concisely replicate this behavior?  I've come up with something along these lines:

```
string = re.sub(r'<(\w+)>', (what here?), string)
```

It might be nice if I could pass a function that maps regex matches to a dict.  Is that possible?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens/do you want to happen with an input containing `<weird> stuff>`? I.e. which assumption do you make on input syntax?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass a callable to `re.sub` to tell it what to do with the match object.

```
s = re.sub(r'<(\w+)>', lambda m: replacement_dict.get(m.group()), s)
```

use of `dict.get` allows you to provide a "fallback" if said word isn't in the replacement dict, i.e.

```
lambda m: replacement_dict.get(m.group(), m.group()) 
# fallback to just leaving the word there if we don't have a replacement
```

I'll note that when using `re.sub` (and family, ie `re.split`), when specifying stuff that exists *around* your wanted substitution, it's often cleaner to use lookaround expressions so that the stuff around your match doesn't get subbed out.  So in this case I'd write your regex like

```
r'(?<=<)(\w+)(?=>)'
```

Otherwise you have to do some splicing out/back in of the brackets in your `lambda`.  To be clear what I'm talking about, an example:

```
s = "<sometag>this is stuff<othertag>this is other stuff<closetag>"

d = {'othertag': 'blah'}

#this doesn't work because `group` returns the whole match, including non-groups
re.sub(r'<(\w+)>', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), m.group()), s)
Out[23]: '<sometag>this is stuff<othertag>this is other stuff<closetag>'

#this output isn't exactly ideal...
re.sub(r'<(\w+)>', lambda m: d.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), s)
Out[24]: 'sometagthis is stuffblahthis is other stuffclosetag'

#this works, but is ugly and hard to maintain
re.sub(r'<(\w+)>', lambda m: '<{}>'.format(d.get(m.group(1), m.group(1))), s)
Out[26]: '<sometag>this is stuff<blah>this is other stuff<closetag>'

#lookbehind/lookahead makes this nicer.
re.sub(r'(?<=<)(\w+)(?=>)', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), m.group()), s)
Out[27]: '<sometag>this is stuff<blah>this is other stuff<closetag>'
```