# Python Regex Sub: Using Dictionary with Regex Expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dictionary, substitution

I am using a dictionary that contain regular expressions to substitute portions of different strings, as elegantly described in [a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545114/python-regex-sub-use-match-as-dict-key-in-substitution) by @roippi. The first 're.sub' expression works perfectly. However, whenever my code actually involves regex expressions (the second 're.sub' expression), the substitutions don't work.

I am very confused as to why this is the case. I have tried both using and taking out the 'r' as well as incorporating the lookahead/lookbehind expressions, nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
test_dict = {r'(\d+)': 'THIS IS A NUMBER', 'john_doe':'THIS IS A NAME'}

re.sub('(john_doe)', lambda x: test_dict.get(x.group(1),x.group(1)),'john_doe_jr')

re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda x: test_dict.get(x.group(1), x.group(1)), '999la')
```

Comment: The `<(\d+)>` pattern does not match anything in `999la`

Comment: Got problems to understand what this achieves. Care to explain?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for your response. I had incorrectly added the html tags, which I have removed. However, this expression should work now (I have tried it in Pythex and it's fine) and it still does not when using the "re.sub" expression. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: The regex matches `999`, which becomes `x.group(1)`. `999` is not a key in `test_dict`, which causes the `.get` method to return `999`, replacing `999` with `999`.

Answer (score 2):

`match.group(n)` does not return the regular expression that was used to match the nth group, but the nth group itself.

The lambda therefore returns `test_dict.get('999', '999')`, which returns `'999'`, because `'999'` is not a key in your dictionary.

You could iterate over the keys of the dictionary and check if any key matches your capture group, and *then* replace it, but that has O(n) time complexity (in the size of the dictionary).

```
def replacement(match, d, group=1):
    for key in d:
        if re.match(key, match.group(group)):
            return d[key]
    return match.group(group)

re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda x: replacement(x, test_dict), '999la')
```

Comment: this function addresses my dilemma perfectly!! Thank you so much.