# Back-referencing in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a large txt file, which I want to edit using Python's `re` module.
Once I find the strings that match my regular expression, I want to make some changes to them and write them back to the txt file.
For example,

**Original text**

```
9 multiplied by 2 is

ans =

18
```

**Desired output**:

```
9 multiplied by 2 is 18.
```

In Atom, I can do this by searching for `([a-z]+)\s+ans\s=\s+(\d+)` and replacing with `$1 $2`.
The `$` grouping does not work with `.sub()` in Python. Any tips on how I can implement this type of backreferencing?

**EDIT**: I am using `?P<tag>` for backreferencing, but that breaks down if I try to do multiple substitutions [using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

in the `re` module instead of using `$1` for group 1 you use `\1` instead. This should allow you to keep your regex as is and convert any other regexes in a similar manner. The proper functionality and definitions are outlined in the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Thanks. This does not work if I try to do multiple substitutions [using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175142/how-can-i-do-multiple-substitutions-using-regex-in-python). Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @aasthas if you are going to use a dictionary (which was not mentioned in your original question) you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22545114/6620283) question, which seems to doing the same thing that are attempting.