# Substitution of string elements using dictionary in python

Tags: python, regex

Based on the answer [Python Regex Sub - Use Match as Dict Key in Substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545114/python-regex-sub-use-match-as-dict-key-in-substitution)

I tried to use my dictionary for the substisutions in string:

```
contractions = { 
"ain't": "have not",
"aren't": "am not",
"can't": "cannot",
"can't've": "cannot have",
"'cause": "because",
"could've": "could have",
"couldn't": "could not",
"couldn't've": "could not have",
"didn't": "did not",
"doesn't": "does not",
"don't": "do not",
"hadn't": "had not",
"hadn't've": "had not have",
"hasn't": "has not",
"haven't": "have not",
"he'd": "he would",
"he'd've": "he would have",
"he'll": "he will",
"he'll've": "he will have",
"he's": "he is",
"how'd": "how did",
"how'd'y": "how do you",
"how'll": "how will",
"how's": "how is",
"i'd": "i would",
"i'd've": "i would have",
"i'll": "i will",
"i'll've": "i will have",
"i'm": "i am",
"i've": "i have",
"isn't": "is not",
"it'd": "it would",
"it'd've": "it would have",
"it'll": "it will",
"it'll've": "it will have",
"it's": "it is",
"let's": "let us",
"ma'am": "madam",
"mayn't": "may not",
"might've": "might have",
"mightn't": "might not",
"mightn't've": "might not have",
"must've": "must have",
"mustn't": "must not",
"mustn't've": "must not have",
"needn't": "need not",
"needn't've": "need not have",
"o'clock": "of the clock",
"oughtn't": "ought not",
"oughtn't've": "ought not have",
"shan't": "shall not",
"sha'n't": "shall not",
"shan't've": "shall not have",
"she'd": "she would",
"she'd've": "she would have",
"she'll": "she will",
"she'll've": "she will have",
"she's": "she is",
"should've": "should have",
"shouldn't": "should not",
"shouldn't've": "should not have",
"so've": "so have",
"so's": "so is",
"that'd": "that had",
"that'd've": "that would have",
"that's": "that is",
"there'd": "there would",
"there'd've": "there would have",
"there's": "there is",
"they'd": "they would",
"they'd've": "they would have",
"they'll": "they will",
"they'll've": "they will have",
"they're": "they are",
"they've": "they have",
"to've": "to have",
"wasn't": "was not",
"we'd": "we would",
"we'd've": "we would have",
"we'll": "we will",
"we'll've": "we will have",
"we're": "we are",
"we've": "we have",
"weren't": "were not",
"what'll": "what will",
"what'll've": "what will have",
"what're": "what are",
"what's": "what is",
"what've": "what have",
"when's": "when is",
"when've": "when have",
"where'd": "where did",
"where's": "where is",
"where've": "where have",
"who'll": "who will",
"who'll've": "who will have",
"who's": "who is",
"who've": "who have",
"why's": " why is",
"why've": "why have",
"will've": "will have",
"won't": "will not",
"won't've": "will not have",
"would've": "would have",
"wouldn't": "would not",
"wouldn't've": "would not have",
"y'all": "you all",
"y'all'd": "you all would",
"y'all'd've": "you all would have",
"y'all're": "you all are",
"y'all've": "you all have",
"you'd": "you would",
"you'd've": "you would have",
"you'll": "you will",
"you'll've": "you will have",
"you're": "you are",
"you've": "you have",
"n\'t": " not",
"\'re": " are",
"\'s": " is",
"\'d": " would",
"\'ll": " will",
"\'t": " not",
"\'ve": " have",
"\'m": " am",
}
```

test = "Hey i'm Yann, how're you and how's it going ? that's interesting: i'd love to hear more about it."
re.sub(r'(\w+)', lambda m: contractions.get(m.group(), m.group()), test)

as a result no substitutions did happen.
But if i use words without "'", then code works fine.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `\w` only matches letters, digits, `_` and some diacritics. You need another regex pattern that will match all of your "words". Try just `r"[\w']+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your response! It's albost correct, but "how're" was not caught(but should be: ""\'re": " are""

Comment: It is matched with `[\w']+` - [proof](https://regex101.com/r/u3ehrP/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I run the code, its's not unfortunately

Comment: It is impossible, you do not have `how're` then in the text.

Comment: `how're` is not in your contractions dictionary, it is matched by the regex pattern

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just a note that python regex isn't the same as java regex. The differences probably won't impact this particular question, so I think your dupe might still be ok